# Converting SQL update based application to java rule based application

Tags: java, lucene, rhino, rule-engine

I have an data centric & data sensitive application, which is written using java, but almost all the business logic is maintained in a .sql files.

These sql files are executed 1 by 1 , temporary table is created and updated by these sql files.

Internally these sql files fire update queries on temporary table with available data values on various conditions.

finally the temporary table is dumped into a physical table.

We are planning to move this to java rule based application as sql scripts are getting huge and hard to understand as well as maintain.

Planning to have all the data in memory using Lucene & its RAMDiirectory, what would be the preferred choice for building rules (these are nothing but update queries in sql)

Was looking @ scripting languages to have dynamic rules, but scripts (rhino / groovy) 
have same characteristics as that of sql files (hard to write & maintain)

Please post your suggestions.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Our company uses [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools). Works really great for us. Drools normally has you write your rules in an XML-based format, but we just extended some of their classes so we could write our rules in Java (allows us to debug the rules at runtime).

Comment: thanks for the response, but would it be a good choice, given a scenarion I dont have well defined work flow and my rules /driving conditions are embedded in bunch of few hundread queries. Please suggest

Comment: I would suggest Drools. It works really well as a rules engine. And if you are interested in work flow and integrating that with web, then I'd look into another JBoss product--Seam. We only use Seam for the JSF side, but it looks to integrate really well with Hibernate and JBPM and I'm guessing it will integrate well with Drools too. But if you only want one part of Seam, then I wouldn't necessarily pick it. Just depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

We also use JBoss Rules / Drools.The newer version (> 4.0.0) has a nice DSL that is perfectly readable and maintainable.No more XML is needed.